# Validation failed: User can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

All,

I am getting the error:  *Validation failed: User can't be blank*.  I am getting this error when I save down a comment. Can anyone point me in the right direction possibly?

**The comments controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
@post = @topic.posts.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:body))

@comment.save!#save the code down in the database

redirect_to [@topic, @post]
end
end
```

**Comment model**

```
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  end
```

**Error on page when saving down to the database**
[image: comment]

Comment: What do you mean by: "I tried with using current_user from Devise in the @comment instance variable, but that did not work for me." Does your comment model include a user ID field?

Comment: I took that out and updated the question.  Yes it does have the  user ID field.  Should I create another instance variable for user_id?  In the comments controller?

Comment: You need to do a better job of explaining what's going on here. Are you trying to work with a nested form? Is this Rails 3? Do you get the error when you call @comment.save! or someplace else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are validating the presence of the user in the comment, but the user is not been assigned to the comment.

Before saving the model, try:
`@comment.user = current_user`